# Как поделить предложение таким образом с помощью регулярных выражений?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть предложение, мне нужно его разделить на слова вот таким образом и раскидать по ячейкам массива. Я пробовала сначала split, но оказалось, что оно удаляет то, что находит регулярное выражение, а мне нужно наоборот.
Как это можно сделать?

(( )+)?(—)?( +)?([А-Яа-я]+)([?.,!]+)?

— Что скажешь? — обратился я к пугалу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так используйте `Pattern` + `Matcher`. Какая у вас версия Java?

Comment: У меня любая или, как минимум, последняя

Comment: Можно  и тот код использовать, да

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: Если не сложно, можете помочь еще с этим? Я не знаю, как сделать так, чтобы регулярное выражение могло отличать слова с частицами (например "что-то" - 1 слово) от других (например "мальчик-волк" - два слова)
https://www.regextester.com/?fam=112734

Comment: Это уже из области NLP. Чтобы написать регулярку, нужно определить, какие именно частицы нужно найти. Желательно иметь побольше примеров.

Comment: Хм, наверное, тогда попробую взять результат от прошлого регулярного выражения и пройтись по нему через https://www.regextester.com/?fam=112735
если выдаст true - значит слово не нужно разделять, если false, то поделить его на два разных через код

Comment: Не используйте regextester, http://regex101.com лучше. Тем более, что лучше тестировать на PCRE, он ближе к Java. `String regex = "(?U)\\b\\p{L}+-(?:то|либо|в-точь|нибудь)\\b"`

Comment: Хорошо, попробую, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
{ String input = "— Что скажешь? — обратился я к пугалу.";
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(( )+)?(—)?( +)?([А-Яа-я]+)([?.,!]+)?");
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
  while(matcher.find()){
   System.out.println(matcher.group());
 }}
```